# How to split a string into two new attributes

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

I have string data that has values that look like `'Washington, DC'` where the City,State is stored in a table attribute called venue_city_state.

I'm trying to split this attribute into two others called venue_city, and venue_state, but when I do

```
UPDATE all_event_details 
SET venue_city = i.venue_city, venue_state = i.venue_state
FROM (SELECT split_part(venue_city_state, ',', 1) AS venue_city, 
  split_part(venue_city_state, ',', 2) AS venue_state 
  FROM all_event_details) i;
```

I only get the first value Washington in venue city, and DC in venue state for **ALL** of my table rows. Not the value in the venue_city_state for that particular row.

How do I change this Update to get venue_city and venue_state out of the venue_city_state for **each** row and not just the **first** row in the table?

Any and all help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a sub-select:

```
UPDATE all_event_details 
    SET venue_city = split_part(venue_city_state, ',', 1), 
        venue_state = split_part(venue_city_state, ',', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Already have a_horse_with_no_name's answer that it's better but you can achieve your purpose with your query adding a WHERE clause to match each row from all_event_details with its corresponding in the secondary select.

```
 UPDATE all_event_details 
 SET venue_city = i.venue_city, venue_state = i.venue_state
 FROM (SELECT id,
              split_part(venue_city_state, ',', 1) AS venue_city, 
              split_part(venue_city_state, ',', 2) AS venue_state 
       FROM all_event_details) i
 WHERE id = i.id;
```

I'm assuming that `id` is all_event_details key.